# Re-Select Changed But Not Saved Item in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.5

```
        TestEntities context = new TestEntities();

        var item = context.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);//item.Name is "Giorgi"

        item.Name = "Hello";

        var item1 = context.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);

        Console.WriteLine(item1.Name);

        context.SaveChanges();
```

What do you expect to be written? Hello is written! **Why?**

```
        TestEntities context = new TestEntities();

        var item = context.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);//item.Name is "Giorgi"

        item.Name = "Hello";

        var item1 = context.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);

        context.SaveChanges();

        Console.WriteLine(item1.Name);
```

What do you expect to be written? Hello is written! **Why?**
*
 *there are two different questions**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your changes are registered in the context, although not saved to the database until you call SaveChanges. If you need the original value, you could either open a new context, [reload the entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reload%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) or inspect the change tracker for changes.

Added tests:

```
[Fact]
public void TestUsingNewContext()
{
    using (var context = new TestEntities())
    {
        var item = context.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);
        item.Name = "Hello";

        using (var newContext = new TestEntities())
        {
            var item1 = newContext.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);

            Assert.Equal("Giorgi", item1.Name);
        }
    }
}

[Fact]
public void TestUsingReload()
{
    using (var context = new TestEntities())
    {
        var item = context.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);
        item.Name = "Hello";

        context.Entry(item).Reload();

        var item1 = context.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);

        Assert.Equal("Giorgi", item1.Name);
    }
}

[Fact]
public void TestUsingChangeTracker()
{
    using (var context = new TestEntities())
    {
        var item = context.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);
        item.Name = "Hello";

        foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<TestTable>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified))
        {
            entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues);
        }

        var item1 = context.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);

        Assert.Equal("Giorgi", item1.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases item and item1 linked with same entity in context. EntityFramework store entity in context for you. I supose when you select it again it returns cached copy. When you change some entity in context anyone who work with this context see this changes. Changes goes to database only after comit.

```
using(TestEntities context = new TestEntities())
{
       var item = context.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);//item.Name is "Giorgi"

       item.Name = "Hello";

       using(TestEntities context = new TestEntities())
       {
           var item1 = context.TestTables.Single(s => s.ID == 1);
           Console.WriteLine(item1.Name); // you will get old value here
       }
}
```

Try to read about it in msdn. Bacause to much stones underwater here. For example: what will be if some one change your entity in db and you try to commit your changes after?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx

Comment: but there is the new select which should take data from db and initialize objects with it

Answer (score 0):

The "context" lives in memory, so when you change stuff in context they are not changed in the database, but they are changed in the "context" (memory), only when you call context.SaveChanges() you actually persisting your updats/changes to the database.

Why would you need SaveChanges() if not to actually save the changes..